# How do I see the full diff when using snapshottest?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm running unit tests with `unittest` in a Python 3.7 project where we are using the `snapshottest` library to keep track of changes in our endpoints. When a snapshot test fails, how do I see the full difference? Right now, the diff is truncated and I can not see what has changed.

Setting maxDiff = None in my test class does not work, since the assertion error is raised within the library and not from my test class.